# Setting the Bounce Address in Apache Commons Mail

Tags: java, email, email-bounces, apache-commons-email

Using the Apache Commons to send email there is the following code.

```
HtmlEmail email = new HtmlEmail();
email.setHostName(SMTP_HOST_NAME);
email.setSmtpPort(587);
email.setAuthenticator(new DefaultAuthenticator(SMTP_AUTH_USER, SMTP_AUTH_PWD));
email.setTLS(true);
email.setBounceAddress("aaa@abc.com");
email.setMsg("Hello");
email.setFrom("bbb@abc.edu");
email.addReplyTo("bbb@abc.edu");
email.addTo("i.do.not.exist@abc.gmail.com");
email.send();
```

But the bounce will not work.  It sends the bounce to the party that authenticated the message, which in this example is SMTP_AUTH_USER.  So How can I get it to bounce properly?

Comment: This appears to be a problem with using gmail as a provider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you check with a packet sniffer what is actually going over the wire? I wouldn't be surprised if the MSA on SMPT_HOST_NAME ignores and overrides your bounce address.

You could try using the SMTP-port to the MTA and quickly check if this makes a difference.

Comment: Well, we are using google email, so I am stuck in that respect.

Answer (score 0):

To set the bounce address you can make use of, setBounceAddress(emailAddressString) method before sending your email.